# Mysql search with returns empty rows

Tags: php, mysql, express

[Followed by this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-json-data-fields-mysql-databases/) i am trying to get all rows in my table with native `json_search` function

```
-- all arts  with keyword  starting 'f':


SELECT * FROM `cushbu_art` WHERE JSON_SEARCH(keyword,'all','f%')
```

But it returns empty row

Here is the values in `keyword` column  `["funny"]`

Comment: `JSON_SEARCH` performs a search on a JSON-formatted string. `'f%'` finds keyword names that start with the letter F. [The Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html).

Comment: My json is valid

Comment: I'm not saying it isn't. I'm saying that your query is going to return the indexes of the JSON "columns" that contain strings starting with the letter F. The link I have provided you with has a section on `JSON_SEARCH` with examples.

Comment: Yeah i know that but the query returns empty

Comment: Can you show us the JSON string, please?

Comment: Could you please update it with an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Thank you.

Comment: Ooops  sqlfiddle not supported JSON cloumn type:)

Comment: What does [JSON_TYPE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-type) return?